# running java web projects using Eclipse and tomcat issue

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have installed tomcat 7.0.37 and Eclipse juno on ubuntu 12.10 and build my first jsp based web app. but when I hit run as -> run on server eclipse shuts down. one issue is that on restart tomcat does not start and pops the error:

> Several ports (8005, 8081, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) are already > in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be >using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the >port number(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, at last I solved it. first I changed the default browser from internal to system default and it solved the eclipse shut down. second I moved the files into the Web Content folder under project structure. and now I have a running JSP application. thanks to all geeks on web.
:)

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat installation folder, you can find a folder called `conf` and in that you can find a XML file `server.xml`.

This file contains the ports Tomcat has to use. Update that file with different port numbers and try again.

Comment: no change. I have changed that several times and tested different free ports.

Comment: Did you checked when you are stopping the server, whether it is shutting down properly OR you are trying to run multiple instances?

Comment: eclipse indicates that the server is stopped but seems that it is not true. how can I stop all instances?

Comment: I am not sure how to kill process in Linux. Kill the tomcat server process and then try.

Comment: I have used `kill -ef #PID` and such but again I had the same problem. right now I restart the system which is not a good solution

Comment: for this issue I ended the process using system monitor. first used `netstat -tulpn` command to list all processes and listening ports then used the system monitor to stop the process. other solutions are mentioned here [end process methods](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/stop-process-ubuntu-linux-command/)

Answer (score 0):

If You use eclipse then double click on servers and double click on tomcat server then one file will open. in that change HTTP port to some other port number and save(ctrl+s) then again start the server . it may be work fine